# Error while trying to start an instance from any process deployed

Tags: spring-boot, bpmn, camunda, bpmn.io

I am having issues integrating Camunda BPMN with springboot, I created file containing the Camunda engine configuration

```java
@Bean
public SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration() {
   SpringProcessEngineConfiguration config = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();
   log.info("--------------------SpringProcessEngineConfiguration ");

  config.setDataSource(datasource);
  PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager=new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  config.setTransactionManager(platformTransactionManager);

  config.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate("true");
  config.setHistory("audit");
  config.setJobExecutorActivate(true);
  config.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
  return config;
}

@Bean
public ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngine() {
  log.info("--------------------processEngine ");
  ProcessEngineFactoryBean factoryBean = new ProcessEngineFactoryBean();
  factoryBean.setProcessEngineConfiguration(processEngineConfiguration());
  factoryBean.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
  return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public RepositoryService repositoryService(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
  log.info("--------------------repositoryService ");
  return processEngine.getRepositoryService();
}

@Bean
public RuntimeService runtimeService(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
   log.info("--------------------runtimeService ");
   return processEngine.getRuntimeService();
 }

@Bean
public TaskService taskService(ProcessEngine processEngine) {
   log.info("-------------------- taskService ");
   return processEngine.getTaskService();
}
```

I did succeed to deploy the process, I guess: I found 2 tables only with data, `ACT_RE_DEPLOYMENT` and `ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY`.

However, I am always getting error while trying to start an instance from any  process deployed .

```
            ProcessEngine processEngine = restProcessEngineProvider.getDefaultProcessEngine();
            log.info("processEngine {} ",processEngine.getName());
            RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
            log.info("runtimeService");
            RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
            log.info("repositoryService");
            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(process.getLastXmlDefinition().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
            DeploymentEntity deploymentResult;
            try {
                deploymentResult = (DeploymentEntity) repositoryService.createDeployment()
                        .name(name)
                        .addInputStream(name, stream).deploy();             
             List<ProcessDefinition> processes=   deploymentResult.getDeployedProcessDefinitions();          
             if (processes!=null)
             {
                 log.info("process not null {} ",processes.size());
             }
             else
             {
                 log.info("process null");
             }
            } finally {
                stream.close();
            }

            //read the result
            String deploymentId = deploymentResult.getId();
            log.info("deployement id {} ",deploymentId);
            ProcessDefinition processDef = repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery()
                    .processDefinitionName(name)
                    .singleResult();
            log.info("process def ...");
            //return the process definition id for later query
            String processDefinitionId="";
            if (processDef!=null)
            {
                if (processDef.getId()!=null)
                 processDefinitionId = processDef.getId();
                else
                    log.info("process def id is null");
            }
            else

            {
                log.info("process def null ");
            }

            log.info("deployed success {} ",processDefinitionId);
            runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey(name);
```

always getting null process def org.camunda.bpm.engine.exception.NullValueException: no processes deployed with key ...

Comment: How do you get the variable `name`? I don't see it being defined in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to answer my own question and I thought I should post it here

```java
String fileXML=""; // set here process  xml 
ProcessEngine processEngine = restProcessEngineProvider.getDefaultProcessEngine();

RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();

RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileXML);
DeploymentEntity deploymentResult;

String deploiementBuild = name + "deploiement";
DeploymentBuilder deploymentBuilder = repositoryService.createDeployment().name(deploiementBuild);
String definitionName = name + ".bpmn";

deploymentBuilder.addInputStream(definitionName, stream);
String deploymentId = deploymentBuilder.deploy().getId();
log.info("depoiement -------------> {}", deploymentId);

List definitions = repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery().list();
log.info("depoiement size ------------> {} ",definitions.size());
```